# MySQL import never completing

Tags: bash, mysql

I wrote a bash script, and here is my problem.  The script run for hours, and it never completes. I see the MySQL import process finish, but the script never gets any further. I have tried adding an `echo` after the MySQL command, but I don't see that `echo` either.  It's like I never get the message that MySQL is complete.

Here is the code for the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PASSWORD="password"

db="dbName"
file=`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql
gunzip $file.gz

mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWORD < $file

 yest= date -d "yesterday 13:00 " '+%Y%m%d'.$db.sql
rm -f $yest

echo Done
```

update:

logged this import and i see:

```
       55 Query UNLOCK TABLES
       55 Query /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */
       55 Query /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */
       55 Query /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */
       55 Query /*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */
       55 Query /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
       55 Query /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */
       55 Query /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */
       55 Query /*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */
       55 Quit
```

as the last command in the logs, which is the last command in the sql file as well.

this is where it hangs...

Comment: Are you sure `gunzip` completes?

Comment: i believe so, because the data is getting pumped into the db and i see the gunzipped sql file in the dir still.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you execute the mysql command yourself?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:  A Better way, just use >> to append to the file.
Note my mistake it's "quit" not ".quit"

mysql probably needs a "quit" command to exit.  You might need to append that to the .sql file

```
#!/bin/bash
USER="user"
PASSWORD="password"
echo "User and Password Set."



db="dbName"
file=`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql
gunzip $file.gz
echo "DB File Unzipped"
echo "quit" >> $file    ####  append .quit command to end of file
echo "" >> $file         #### just to make sure there is a return at the end of the previous line
mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWORD < $file

yest= date -d "yesterday 13:00 " '+%Y%m%d'.$db.sql
rm -f $yest

echo Done
```

Comment: i understand what you are saying here and think you are on the right track. this brings up another question though.  the sql file is the result of mysqldump on another server, there is no human intervention, so how can i add append "quit" to the sql file?

Comment: @bart2puck, I made edits to the above.  This should make the changes you need. Let me know if this doesn't work and I will see if I can figure out why.

Comment: hmm. running into a  problem now where, just running in mysql < file.sql  never ends...forget about the bash script for now..

Comment: What does file.sql look like at the very end of the file? My guess is it is hung up on something.   What happens if you just run that command on the command line?

Comment: i turned on logging and this query takes a really long time.Query /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ts_uf_audioDescriptiveInfo` ENABLE KEYS */

Comment: although when doing show full processlist, i dont see that query working....  then end of that file is "quit" and then a carrage return.

Comment: see updates....

Comment: Just to prove that it is one of the statements taking a long time, you might try this with a file that only contains the line with the quit and return. This will tell you if it is one of the statements or the bash script. The fact that the log shows the quit seems to imply that the bash script still seems to be hanging.

Comment: i have done that, and flat file works.  i have also just done mysql < file.sql from command line and that hangs too.  something in the mysql sql file.  but like i said, i see in the logs it completes and never ends.